# jQuery document ready functions not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a form with 5 divs and to keep the form as clean and tidy as possible, I kept 4 of them hidden with "display: none".

When the button (ex. Add Client) is clicked, I want the next div (up to 4 more) to be displayed with a js, and when the other button (ex. Remove Client) is clicked, I want the last displayed div to be hidden again.

**JS:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function addClient() {/*mycode*/});

    $(document).ready(function removeClient() {/*mycode*/});
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<input id="kkBtnNewClient" type="button" value="New Client" class="kkButton" onclick="addClient()"/>

<input id="kkBtnRemoveClient" type="button" value="Remove Client" class="kkButton" onclick="removeClient()"/>
```

I tried to put a simple alert in the /*mycode*/ part, but I don't even get to that part.

Comment: I think you're using document.ready incorrectly. try creating those functions on a single document.ready function.

Comment: function is no need to scope inside readyfunction

Comment: Can you please include a working (reproducing the issue) example? create an HTML\CSS\JS snippet and include what's relevant please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you pass to `ready()` is *called when the ready event fires*.

It does not create a global variable from which to call the function.

Use a function declaration to do that. Better yet, bind the event handler with JavaScript and don't use `onclick` attributes at all.

```js
$("#kkBtnNewClient").on("click", function addClient() {
  alert("add client");
});

$("#kkBtnRemoveClient").on("click", function removeClient() {
  alert("remove client");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="kkBtnNewClient" type="button" value="New Client" class="kkButton" />

<input id="kkBtnRemoveClient" type="button" value="Remove Client" class="kkButton" />
```

Comment: I have no idea why this is not working, I'm sure i'm missing something. I'll just give up.

Comment: I copied that same code and it's not working, not blaming you, I simply can't understand why it's not working.

Comment: Possibly you need to move the script element (with the calls to `$` in it) so it appears after the input elements

Comment: That didn't work, but I noticed that using a button nstead of input, it works, but it keep refreshing the page every button click, any thoughts?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference to the JS unless there is some other code interfering. Submit buttons submit forms (which cause browsers to navigate to the response to the form submission), that is what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like as below:

```js
$(".group_1").hide();
$(".group_2").hide();

$(document).on('click','#kkBtnNewClient', function(){
 console.log("kkBtnNewClient clicked");
    $(".group_1").show();
    $(".group_2").hide();

 
});

$(document).on('click','#kkBtnRemoveClient', function(){
  $(".group_2").show();
  $(".group_1").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="group_1">
div 1
</div>
<div class="group_1">
div 2
</div>
<div class="group_1">
div 3
</div>
<div class="group_1">
div 4
</div>
<div class="group_2">
div 5
</div>
<input id="kkBtnNewClient" type="button" value="New Client" class="kkButton" />
<input id="kkBtnRemoveClient" type="button" value="Remove Client" class="kkButton" />
```